# R add newlines to every nth occurrence of blank

Tags: r, line, addition, find-occurrences

Mytext is a long string delimited by blank space.

```
Mytextsample <- "aaaaabb cccdddd eee adssdada ooeoeo ososs ksdkd
ooeresso osososososos krrr dkdkkd odlcjs kdcmcmc ddddd dmssss"
```

I tried to add a new line every 10th blank using regular expressions
How can I use a text replace function such as `gsub` or `str_replace`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution first uses `strsplit()` your string into a vector at each space, `split()` it after every 10th item and uses `paste0()` to reassemble each level using `sapply()`:

```
Mytextsample <- "aaaaabb cccdddd eee adssdada ooeoeo ososs ksdkd
  ooeresso osososososos krrr dkdkkd odlcjs kdcmcmc ddddd dmssss"

dat <- unlist(strsplit(Mytextsample, " ")) # unlist is here to convert to a vector
dat <- split(dat, ceiling(seq_along(dat)/10))

out <- sapply(dat, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = " "))
out
```

Comment: No problems, please [up-vote and accept](//https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if you think it is the best solution for your problem.